# PHP convert to transparent doesn't literally make it transparent

Tags: php, image, transform, photo, photoshop

I'm trying to make **imageA.png** transparent then merge it to another fully transparent image using `imagecopy` function, But after merging, **imageA.png** becomes white background instead of transparent

- I believe it is because it was not converted to transparent properly

Here's what I used
This is a stand-alone file to convert the image to transparent ( It works ) :

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng("imageA.png");
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($img, $white);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
```

and this one is to merge the above result with another transparent image

```
$src = imagecreatefrompng("imageA_transparent.png");
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('another_transparent_image.png');
imagesavealpha($dest, true);
imagealphablending($dest, true);

imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 400);
```

the result is `imageA_transparent.png` becomes with white background while it is actually transparent over the second transparent used image  (another_transparent_image.png)

- I tried using a normal photoshopped transparent image **and it worked** with no problem
- I tried to use both `imagesavealpha` and `imagealphablending` with `$src` and no effect
- Both images are properly transparent before using `imagecopy`

** Finally, when i tried to open `imageA_transparent.png` ( The php-generated transparent image ), **In photoshop**, it appeared with white background and locked layer, This means PHP didn't convert it to transparent/png properly ( I believe )

Comment: **Solution : I used Imagick convert as an alternative for php-to-transparent convert and everything worked fine, Now I want an alternative for imagick because i dont want any based frameworks or so whatever, Is there anyway to make a proper convert from to remove white background without using imagick, just PHP based functions

Comment: Try making the very first colour you allocate with `imagecolorallocate()` a transparent pixel. Allocate white as your second.